# Setting max() to null in MYSQL when no max() exists

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with SQL. I'm currently developing a website that has a guitar tuner built into the website. The user is allowed to create instruments and store the information about their tunings. The problem is if a user creates a new instrument there is table that will show them their created instruments in the website. However the instrument will not appear until it has been logged as tuned.

These is an issue with an SQL stored procedure. I have the Date of the tuning in the table set to max meaning if an instrument hasn't been tuned it won't show up.
The Date is setup as a DATETIME in MYSQL

The stored procedure looks like this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectallinstruments`()
BEGIN
SELECT b.Username, a.Name, a.Type, a.ID, max(c.Date) as lasttuned
FROM instruments a, Users b, instrumenttuner c
WHERE a.Users_ID = b.ID and c.Instrument_ID = a.ID
group by a.ID order by b.ID asc, a.ID asc;
END
```

Is there a way to make lasttuned in this instance equal null when there is no record for the instrument so that the table will print the instrument with no date record attached to it when the instrument was created.

Comment: what is the result that you are getting currently

Comment: `SELECT b.Username, a.Name, a.Type, a.ID, 
       max(c.Date) as lasttuned
FROM instruments a
join Users b ON a.Users_ID = b.ID
left join instrumenttuner c ON c.Instrument_ID = a.ID
group by a.ID 
order by b.ID asc, a.ID asc;`

Comment: I'm currently only getting records of instruments where they have a date value already if that makes sense.

Comment: check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: Thank you juergen d Thats Worked Brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.

What you want is a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select u.Username, i.Name, i.Type, i.ID, max(c.Date) as lasttuned
from instruments i left join
     users u
     on i.users_ID = u.ID left join
     instrumenttuner it
     on it.Instrument_ID = i.ID
group by i.ID
order by u.ID asc, i.ID asc;
```

In general, you want to be careful about having columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  In this case, it is okay, because you are aggregating by the primary key of a table and using additional columns from that table or unique for the primary key.